# Summing thousands of rasters in GRASS GIS (after reach r.series limit)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, grass-7.6

I am using GRASS GIS 7.6 and want to sum 30.000 small rasters from a total viewshed calculation. I tried the following approach: 1-> r.list to get a list of the names of the rasters. 2 -> r.series (sum) to sum all the rasters, but there is a limit on the number of rasters that I can sum in each take...

Can anyone provide help with this?

Maybe the solution is some python coding which loops the sum.

Answer (score 2):

from the r.series manual:

> Management of open file limits The maximum number of raster maps that
>   can be processed is given by the user-specific limit of the operating
>   system. For example, the soft limits for users are typically 1024
>   files. The soft limit can be changed with e.g. ulimit -n 4096
>   (UNIX-based operating systems) but it cannot be higher than the hard
>   limit. If the latter is too low, you can as superuser add an entry in:
>
> /etc/security/limits.conf>
>                      your_username  hard    nofile      4096

in my linux ubuntu 18 it defaults to:

```
<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
root            hard    core            100000
```